# Can't Include navigation property (it is null)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the students  from the database and also include the course entities corresponding to them, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

this is student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }  

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

this is course class:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and I retrive the collection of student entities as shown below:

```
context.Students.Include(i => i.Course).ToList();
```

If I remove the include method, then I get data, but course property of student object is null.

P.S I am testing it with Postman and with "Include" I am not able to get anything.

**If I comment this**

```
public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
```

**everything works fine.**

I put the full code on github:

https://github.com/AlexDev5/Problem

Comment: I mean that data "Could not get any response" is shown in postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure the serializer to ignore circular references in your project.

So for this you have to add following line of code inside `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`

Like

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
}
```

Comment: I think, my situation is a bit different. In older versions, I had not problem too..

Comment: @A.M., see the result in image.

Comment: Are you testing it in ASP.NET Core WEB API 2 with Entity Framework core? maybe there is difference

Comment: I have a project with web api not core and its working well

Comment: are you using in web api core?

Comment: Yes, I am. I debuging my code now and I think that there is a problem with the getter of Students property in course class..

Comment: @A.M., please view edited answer may it help you.

Comment: I have project where objects  have huge amount of properties, so I think this won't be best solution for this situation (in this case more code is needed to be written). I have put the code on github: https://github.com/AlexDev5/Problem

Comment: Then, Did you got any solution?

Comment: Yes, I updated the ConfigureServices method in StartUp.cs file..The problems was that I wasn't handling Json reference looping

Comment: Ohh well done :)

Comment: @A.M. I asked my co-worker about you problem and they gave me a simple solution, I update my answer now, please view updated answer, may it help you. :)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. the question referenced by Ivan Stoev has the same solution. I solved my problem in this way.

Comment: @A.M, glad to hear you have get rid from your problem :)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know WPF? I have one question.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51498387/bind-selected-item-to-combobox-with-caliburn-micro

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the sample found here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Querying/Querying

I wrote one solution, but I don't know if it is good approach for this problem:

I created StudentCourse class and defined it as shown below:

```
public class StudentCourse
{
    public int StudentCourseID { get; set; }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Student Student{ get; set; }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

And I modified the Course class as shown below:

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But this is totally different (many-to-many) relationship with additional link table. While the original design is one-to-many. `Include` should work correctly in both cases, except if your database schema doesn't match the model.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I tested it in debug mode several times and the problem arises when debugger comes to `get` in `public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }`. So, If I remove this line of code, problem dissapears..

Comment: I have put the source code on github... https://github.com/AlexDev5/Problem

Comment: *"If I remove "Students" virtual property from the Course class, I get what I need."* - then your problem has nothing to do with EF Core, but the Json serialization of objects with circular references. There are plenty of posts here on SO of how to configure Json reference loop handling. For instance, the one that I marked as duplicate.

Comment: thank you, I will read about it...