# Bind Selected Item to comboBox with caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have seen and tested a lot of material about this and I have the problem again. I have a collection of cities bound to the combobox and I want to set the selected item (selected city) when I click the button (for simplicity)

this is my combobox in xaml:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Margin="65,10,0,0"
                              Height="25"
                              Name="Cities"
                              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                              Width="71">

                    </ComboBox>
```

this is code in corresponding ViewModel:

```
private City _selectedCity;
public City SelectedCity
{
    get { return _selectedCity; }
    set
      {
         _selectedCity = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedCity);
         MessageBox.Show(SelectedCity.Name);
      }
}
```

When I click the button this line of code is executed:

```
SelectedCity = CitySecond;
```

where, CitySecond is one random item from the Cities Collection.

When I click this button the desired city name appears in MessageBox, but nothing changes in combobox. I tested it in Debug mode  and everything looks fine, but as it seems comboBox doesn't feels that something has changed.

I have also added the following line of code in combobox xaml definition but nothing changed:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCity}"
```

What Can I do?

EDIT:

I have created another project, where everything works fine, but here is mystery. Does anything other affects the combobox to work properly?

Comment: check whether items collection available for combobox and then in button click just add your city to items collection.

Comment: collection is avalaible to combobox and the first element in the items is selected. adding city will cause duplication of data and it's not a good approach as I think...

Comment: Then you have to check first is there any item already exist in collection or not. Now m leave from my office 2moro i'll try for it

Comment: I know that it always exists...

Comment: In debug did you check the DataContext of the combo to see if it's the view model?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't be able to attach the collection of cities...

Comment: @A.M. I'll try to solve your problem with my colleagues, If we got success then update you soon

Comment: good.. now I am trying to create same situation and see the same situation in another project..

Comment: I found out that it is not binding problem. it is another problem in my project...